# How to make a non-square contourf-plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using contourf in pyplot to plot some scalar data, but when my domain is non-square i feel like the data is misrepresented because it always plots it in a square (though the axis values will increase faster on one side.) How can i force the axis scaling to be equal, such that if my domain is twice as long in the x-direction the image is actually plotted in a rectangle with this property?

I'm doing something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
contour = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z)
fig.colorbar(contour)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This might help](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#make-the-aspect-ratio-for-plots-equal):

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect="equal")
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `ax.set_aspect`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x=np.r_[-10:10:100j]
y=np.r_[-20:20:100j]
z= np.add.outer(x*x, y*y)
contour=ax.contour(x,y,z)
fig.colorbar(contour)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
# ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

while changing `ax.set_aspect('equal')` to

```
ax.axis('equal')
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the axis setting:

```
axis('equal')
```

See all of the axis settings here:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis