# how to change the shape of a contour in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, contour, contourf

I am using `contour` or `contourf` in `matplotlib`

And the data is a 2D array with values in, like this:

```
1 2 3 3 3
2 3 3 4 1
2 3 4 5 6
...
```

The result I got is as below.
[image]

It is like a square, while actually, the y extent is 600+ and x extent is only 350.
So the figure should look like a rectangle, not a square.

But I looked into the arguments in `contour` and `contourf`, there is no argument about changing the shape of the contour, or changing the length of the axis.

for Adobe, here is the simplified code of my case:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
m = [[1,2,3,4],
[2,3,4,5],
[2,2,1,5]]

print m
plt.contourf(m)
plt.show()
```

Then, in this situation, how to use ax.axis()?

Comment: Now I got the useful solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418712/how-to-make-a-non-square-contourf-plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably You want to set equal scale:

```
ax.axis('equal')
```

**Edit**

Here's Your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

m = [[1,2,3,4],
     [2,3,4,5],
     [2,2,1,5]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.contourf(m)
ax.axis('equal')

fig.savefig("equal.png")
```

[image]

matplotlib has three interfaces. Here's the same code written to utilize each of them:

1. machine-state:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
   y = np.sin(x)
   plt.plot(x, y)
   plt.show()
   ```
2. pylab:

   ```
   from pylab import *
   x = arange(0, 10, 0.2)
   y = sin(x)
   plot(x, y)
   show()
   ```
3. object-oriented:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
   y = np.sin(x)
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
   ax.plot(x, y)
   plt.show()
   ```

I prefer object-oriented interface: it gives full control on what is going on. I cited solution for that one.

Comment: Thank you for that, but do I have to import which lib? It doesn't work maybe because I need do something else, but this did help me to find the solution, thanks.

Comment: @rankthefirst: I can't tell -- unless You post minimal working example reproducing Your problem. You shouldn't import anything for this solution. But Yo might have used pylab interface, while I posted a solution tested with pyplot interface. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related).